# Reindex all of ElasticSearch with Curator?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

Is there a Recipe out there to Reindex all ElasticSearch Indices with Curator?

I'm seeing that it can Reindex a set of indices into one (Daily to Month use case), however I don't see anything that would suggest it could easily apply a new mapping file to every Elastic Index.

I'm taking a guess I'll need to write a wrapper script around Curator to grab index names and feed them into Curator.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got you right as you mentioned reindexing and mapping changes...

If you want to set/update a mapping in a collection of indices and if you know the indices to update by name (or pattern), you are able to apply the same mapping or a mapping change at once with https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#_multi_index_2

For reindexing, there is no way to specify multiple source/target pairs at once but you can split one index into many. But as you sugessted, you can use subsequent calls to the reindex api.

BTW: The reindex api does not copy the settings nor mappings from the source into the destination index. You need to handle it by yourself, maybe using https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/indices-templates.html

Comment: I thought the Put Mapping would only update it for new data into that index, if I wanted the entire index to reflect the new mapping, does Put Mapping do that?

Comment: Sure, as the documentation clearly states: The PUT mapping API allows you to add fields to an existing index or to change search only settings of existing fields. What is exactly your change/use case you want to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to move from one Mapping to a new improved Mapping for a number of time-series indices.  They're rolled over daily, and new ingest goes into the new daily index.  One specific example in the new mapping is adding a new analyzer to index the fields as a raw value, as well as, tokenized.

Comment: in that case i would set a index template for the new indices and start reindexing into the new ones. the template will be applied, as soon the index will be created. works perfectly with rolling indices as long you specify a valid index name pattern.